# Enemy moving towards Player in a 2D setting?

Tags: unity, 2d, movement

i want to apologize if this seems so basic, but I'm having trouble having an Enemy move in my Player's Direction in a 2D Top-Down game.

I already saw a lot of other answers but they all use the `.LookAt()` and `.Forward` but i'm not using rotations so i cannot just move them in the direction they are looking at, i just need to move them along X and Y, and i managed to do a pretty horrible workaround :

`//I tried getting the difference between player and enemy positions, but this is relative, and slows down the closer it gets to the player.`

`Vector2 distance = new Vector2(player.position.x - enemy.position.x, player.position.y - enemy.position.y);`

`enemy.AddForce(distance * walkspeed);`

So, how could i make the Enemy move in the direction the Player is, but with a constant speed?

Comment: distance.Normalize()

Comment: Any example of how to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a constant rate of movement for your *walkspeed*, you can normalize your distance between the player and the enemy.
A normalized vector still points to its original direction, however it has a length of 1, thus, getting you constant results when multiplying with your *walkspeed*.

The math behind it, for a vector *v* to its normalized version *vn*:

```
vn = normalize(v)
<=> v / length(v)
<=> v / sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y)
```

In Unity, you can simply use the *normalized* property of a Vector. In your case, this would be:

```
Vector2 distance = new Vector2(player.position.x - enemy.position.x, player.position.y - enemy.position.y);
distance = distance.normalized;
```

If you multiply this vector with your *walkspeed* variable, it will always have a length of *walkspeed*, provided, that the initial distance is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Im really surprised nobody mentionned `Vector2.MoveTowards()`.

Here's the method definition:

```
public static Vector2 MoveTowards(Vector2 current, Vector2 target, float maxDistanceDelta);
```

you would use it as such:

```
Vector2.MoveTowards(player.position, enemy.position, someValueYouDetermine);
```

Moves a point current towards target.

> This is essentially the same as Vector2.Lerp but instead the function
>   will ensure that the speed never exceeds maxDistanceDelta. Negative
>   values of maxDistanceDelta pushes the vector away from target.